# Android - turn GPS on or off programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, google-play-services, android-location

Why we need to go setting for on/off GPS on the other hand we can on/off WIFI and Bluetooth programmatically without move to settings.
Android Guidelines have changed above version 4.0. You cannot change GPS off on programmatically for versions above 4.0.

Comment: Why Google change this  for GPS not for others

Comment: thats call security @Arunkumar

Comment: go on ask google. if u wish you can report from here https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html

Comment: Wifi or Data connection can also call security , we can also get the user's location from network provider .

Comment: Location provided by network provider will never be accurate.

Comment: but network provider can provide the approximate location that can also security call,  Also GPS not accurate inside the building or not give the correct location inside the building.

Comment: GPS uses high battery power if u remember that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There used to be a way to enable / disable GPS programmatically by sending the `android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE` broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", enabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

where `enabled` would be `true` or `false` respectively.

If you take a look at [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35924), this hack was subverted in Android 4.4. It still works on older OS versions.

Now the answer to your question

> Why we need to go setting for on/off GPS on the other hand we can
>   on/off WIFI and Bluetooth programmatically without move to settings ?

Android's GPS technology periodically sends location data to Google even when no third-party apps are actually using the GPS function. **A lot of people are very sensitive about things like real-time location monitoring .** That's why Google made it mandatory to get the user's consent before using the GPS function. The following dialog is seen whenever the user turns GPS on:

[image: GPS user permission]

And hence it is no longer possible to *programmatically* change the GPS settings, as by necessity it requires the user's permission. What the programmer *can* do is direct the user to the GPS settings by calling

```
startActivity(context, new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

and let the user make a choice.

As an interesting point, if you try sending the `GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE` broadcast on the new OS versions, you get a

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
    not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE
```

error. As you can see, its a `SecurityException` with a *permission denial* message.

Answer (score 4):

The premise of your question is no longer correct.  With Google Play Services 7, you can display a dialog to change the location provider settings from within your app.  Jump to 1:10 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0Kh_RnSM0w).

Comment: Note that this still involves the user, though it's more convenient (and offers a better UX) than is popping over to the Location screen in the Settings app. It also introduces a dependency on Play Services, and therefore will not be available on non-Google Play-ecosystem devices (e.g., Kindle Fire series, BlackBerry 10).